# Redux-form access form's values from inside the form's instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux-form

From my understanding from [the docs](http://redux-form.com/6.6.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/) if i access `props.values` from inside a component instance, I should get an object describing the values in each field of the form.

> values : Object
>
> The current values of all the fields in the form.

In my case, I need to access a value, in order to redirect to something like

`signup?email=theemailvalue`

upon form submission.

However when I access the `props.value` I get an empty object.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As redux-form documentation, proper way to access form values is by [formValueSelector](http://redux-form.com/6.6.0/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/)

Comment: Thanks, that was it. 

However now, I am confused. What is this ['instance API'](http://redux-form.com/6.6.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/) then, mentioned in every component's documentation? How/when do you use it? It is a little confusing having a `values` there describing it as 'The current values of all the fields in the form' and then it does nothing

Comment: The "instance API" is stuff you can call/access on a _reference_ (an "instance" in OO-speak) to your form component (from its parent).